# Communicate between python and browser debugger console

Tags: javascript, python

Is there any way through which you can communicate between python and chrome/IE/mozilla debugger console? I mean, can I externally call debugger console in any major browser from python code and expect to see the output in python IDE? My goal is to be able to pass .js file to the debugger console, run it in a background and return the output to the IDE in which I work.

For those who advise doing google search first, I was not able to find anything worthy. Might be, small snippet might do which I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Best of my understanding, you can use SeleniumHQ's browser automation.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

To be more specific to your answer.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#using-javascript

1. Simple example on a page that has jQuery loaded:

`element = driver.execute_script("return $('.cheese')[0]")`

2. Finding all the input elements to the every label on a page:

`labels = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("label")
inputs = driver.execute_script(
    "var labels = arguments[0], inputs = []; for (var i=0; i < labels.length; i++){" +
    "inputs.push(document.getElementById(labels[i].getAttribute('for'))); } return inputs;", labels)`

I hope it helps. :-)